# 60s-70s F&SF story: suicidal woman, angel, crows taking over people's thoughts

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I used to read *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction* as a kid, in the late 60s to early 70s. A particular story I remember was of a woman who was depressed and contemplating suicide, but she was visited by an angel who helped her. The angel (Ariezekel????? can't remember his name) explained that crows were taking over people's thoughts and that's why they were killing themselves. Something along those lines. Ring any bells? I'd love to find that story....

Comment: I do did you read that mag?

Comment: In the Name of the Bird!

Answer (score 5):

I found it!  The short story is called "Dormant Soul" by Josephine Saxton.  It was published in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, February 1969.  That issue also contains a very weird story by Vance Aandahl called "Drool".

The story was reprinted in the book *[The Power of Time](https://sfmistressworks.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/the-power-of-time-josephine-saxton/)*. This link contains a description of the book's contents, including "Dormant Soul":

From the above link:

> The protagonist is a thirty-five-year-old woman who lives alone. One
>   night she is visited by an angel, who reveals he is actually a visitor
>   from another planet. It seems she is at risk of being possessed, or
>   has been possessed, by demons from another planet, and Armaziel has
>   come to free her. Part of the cure involves getting seven random
>   people to pray for her. So she rings names she has picked from the
>   phone book, and it seems to work.

Comment: Can you provide any details that suggest similarity, while you may be right, this will help other users who stumble through confirm this is the right book quicker. Here's a good little [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/68872)

Comment: Don't forget you can [edit] all these things into your answer!

Comment: If you do want some help with that, I'll happily help (say you're struggling with formatting, etc!)